# get the $(this) string

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, this

I need the content of `$(this)` in a function, I want to know the string inside this

```
;(function($) {
  $.fn.extend({
    myFunction : function () {
     // if this contain "tr" i have to do some ...
    }
  });
  $("#myTable tbody tr").myFunction();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the string inside`? Do you mean the tag name? -- `this.tagName`.

Comment: what do you mean by content of $(this)?  The html contained in the element this?

Comment: i need the string "#myTable tbody tr"

Answer (score 0):

You can access the selector inside your jQuery method via `this.selector` like so:

```js
;(function($) {

   $.fn.extend({
        myFunction: function () {
            console.log(this.selector);
        }
    });
    $("#myTable tbody tr").myFunction();

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However, generally it would be preferable to detect if your element is a `tr` or a child of a `tr` using `this.is('tr')` or `this.is('tr *')` instead, rather than trying to parse the selector.